# Is there a way to center file on cursor like Emacs Ctrl-L, but in IntelliJ?

Tags: file, intellij-idea

Is there a way to center file on cursor like Emacs <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, but in IntelliJ?  I'd like to better scroll through a file with IntelliJ.  When I reach the bottom of the viewable screen I'd like to hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to center the file with the cursor in the middle of the screen.

Comment: FWIW, the inbuilt vi keymap has this with the usual vi command of `zz`.

Comment: @GregKopff What is the name of this command? Is there a way we can assign a new keybinding to that command?

Comment: @modulitos I don't know sorry. I looked under Keymap settings but search of `zz` doesn't show anything, so it may be "internal" to the vi plugin.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to scroll to center. M = middle.

Comment: Not on a Mac.  Ctrl+m goes to matching brace/paren.  Cmd+m hides the application (enforced by OS).

Comment: Is there the opposite shortcut. A key sequence that moves the cursor in the center of the screen?

Comment: There is no default shortcut in the default MacOS keymap. You need to assign a shortcut to the action `Scroll to Center`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as you like just go to **File ->Settings ->IDE settings ->keymap -> then set your shortcut.**

To move to the beginning/end of a file, use `ctrl+home/ctrl+end` on `Windows/Unix`

or `command-home and command-end` on the `Mac`

On my windows in set the shortcuts to

`crtl+m` -> to scroll to middle of the file

`crtl+up` -> to scroll to up

`crtl+down` -> to scroll to down

Answer (score 0):

As of 1st of March 2019
In IntelliJ idea | Android Studio

1. Go to setting **File -> Settings ->IDE settings -> keymap**
2. Search for "center" and set shortcut

here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXYSi.png